# Can we have a reply button in comments too?

Tags: feature-request, chat, comment-replies

Can we have a reply button as in chat along with the upvote and flag in comments followed by posts.

See this chat :Here we have a reply button

[image]

And this comments under a post:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See ["Reply" links on comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2051/reply-links-on-comments).

If you have trouble installing, read the instructions [here](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info)

Comment: Will this work in math and physics too?

Comment: @exploringnet: yes, everywhere

Comment: Working now. Replied using that. :P

Comment: Was you notified about my comment. I now see It does not include @  in it?

Comment: Again @ is not here.. What is problem?

Comment: @exploringnet: No need to @ _me_ on _my_ post. It gets removed since I get notified anyway.

Comment: the problems is that it may notify incorrectly http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192734/i-got-notified-of-a-comment-reply-meant-for-someone-else .

Answer (score 3):

There is a stackapp script that will do that for you.

["Reply" links on comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2051/reply-links-on-comments)

[image]