# I got notified of a comment @reply meant for someone else

Tags: bug, comments, notifications, comment-replies

Yesterday, I was commenting [on a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149913/search-distinct-values-in-datatable#comment26583845_18149913), and another user named **Chris** was also commenting.  I came back on a while later, and I had a notification on the question. I went to check the question and saw that the original poster had replied in a comment, but used `@Chris` as the user they were pointing the comment to.

Should I have been notified for this? Or was there some logic confusion between my name (christiandev) and the other users' name (Chris)?

[image]

Comment: Care to link to the comments in question? But yeah, if it matches a partial name, you will get notified as well.

Comment: I will dig through and try and find it, but I will definitely take note if it happens again.  Is the partial match an expected behavior?

Comment: Afaik yes http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: As far as I understand (see #4 in the linked answer), both people will *not* be notified. Matching happens in reverse-chronological order, so you were notified because you were the last Chris that was participating. The other Chris is blissfully unaware.

Comment: So, this is **correctly** marked as a bug or an undesired behavior?

Comment: Not sure what the official opinion is. It has been discussed before, both [in the context of chat notifications](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73931/getting-marcs-chat-notifications) and [as a somewhat-related feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125994/how-to-reply-to-one-user-among-two-having-same-names).

Comment: OK, my 2P worth would be to alert the user it's aimed at, but then that takes away the ability to shorthand in the comment I guess.  Im sure there's more thought that my 20 mins worth gone into it :)

Comment: To me the sensible thing would be to be to find all possible targets of the `@` and have exact matches trump partial matches. Otherwise if Chris comments before christiandev there is no way they can be notified.

Comment: Well _I_ think we should get someone from the C++ committee who designed the overload resolution rules to see if they can formalize the `@`reply semantics - then that situation would become undefined behavior and you'd get a unicorn when attempting to post the comment.

Comment: @Arjan - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149913/search-distinct-values-in-datatable#comment26583845_18149913). The auto complete gives the impression that Chris would have been notified. [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BHwFE.png). I would definitely expect that selecting the "Chris" option would notify Chris.

Comment: You're right, @Martin, though the rules indicate that indeed `@Chris` first matches "christiandev" in reverse chronological order (and there's no way to explicitly select "Chris" in this case), the auto complete *does* suggest otherwise.

Comment: Now there is auto complete I wonder about the value of even catering for partial matches TBH. Sometimes it makes it confusing who the response is intended for.

Comment: As an aside, mobile (for me) does not have auto complete, @Martin. Also, the auto complete does not include editors, though even an editor named "Chrissy" would have matched in this situation.

Comment: @Arjan Ah I didn't realise that mobile didn't have that.

Comment: And, @Martin, if two users are named "Chris", then even the auto complete would be confusing. But surely things *could* be improved, if the team would feel like it.

Comment: Well the issue is already solved in chat. Just a reply link next to the comment would do it. Prioritising exact matches over partial matches seems like something that should be easy to do with the current system though even though the edge case of people with the exact same user name would still crop up occasionally.

Comment: @Arjan - I'm pretty sure it does because the replied to comment is permanently linked to the other commment. (You can click on it to navigate to the comment it was in reply to) so there should be no possible ambiguity or need to parse names at all.

Comment: @CodyGray - Really? You just asked a question in the comment above. Why you would not want to be notified of responses to it?

Comment: Related: [Can we have a reply button in comments too?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178055/can-we-have-a-reply-button-in-comments-too)

Comment: Chat’s message references would be nice. Or maybe @user84237 (Arjan)?

Comment: @arjan just testing is comment reply really case sensitive??

Comment: @sHa, no it's not. Why would you think that?

Comment: @Arjan oops, blonde moment. Saw this in the answer below: "Comment `@replies` are case insensitive" and for some reason read it as "Comment `@replies` are case sensitive"! :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's what happened:

You were both commenting on the post. `christiandev` and `Chris` start with the same five letters. Comment @replies are case insensitive.

When this happens, the system's default is to pick the *last* commenter. Since you had commented chronologically just before Chris, the system pinged you. See rule 5 in [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). This is definitely a bug; if there is an exact match for a name, the system *should* go with that. However, the system currently defaults to rules 4 and 5 in conflicts. This means that you, chronologically, were notified.

I propose bypassing the rule set if an exact match is found. While this is currently technically by design, it really shouldn't be.