# Reply to comment button

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies

I would propose to add a small reply button when you want to reply on a comment, just like in chat:

> [image: chat reply icon]

Sometimes it is hard to get the exact name of the person right, since he/she uses foreign symbols as first characters in his/her username. It seems a very simple, yet effective solution.

Clicking this button will put the `@username` in the 'Add Comment' box, just like you would normally type this yourself.

Comment: One of the most often-asked-for feature requests, surprised you didn't find [one of the dupes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4798?lq=1) when searching.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Indeed. Didn't show up when I searched for it. My bad I guess.

Comment: No big deal... now with Jeff out of the way a fat bounty might make the team reconsider his decision to decline. :)

Comment: I am not sure that is the correct dupe. While strongly related, and both mention a reply-to link, the linked feature request is from before the @name system was even implemented, and as far as I can tell resulted in the implementation of said system. This feature request asks to change or add to the existing system.

Comment: @HugoRune: You are right. That one did I find too, guess I clicked 'okay, this is a dup' too soon.

Comment: [This one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178055/can-we-have-a-reply-button-in-comments-too) fits better as a dup, but the accepted answer is a stackapp script.